# how to install Bitnami lampstack on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, lamp, bitnami

I want to Install **Bitnami Lampstack** on my Ubuntu 14.04 .

I downloaded it from [bitnami website](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) but its not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create an account in [bitnami website](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) to download the **bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run** file.
Then copy the file to your desktop (for convenience ). To provide read and exicution permission, Open terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T).
and type

```
chmod 755 chmod  755 'location of bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Better drag and drop the .run file from your desktop after typing `chmod 755`, press enter.

Now double click on the .run file. It will guide you through the installation process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got to directory where downloaded that file

then enter following commands

considering Downloaded filename e.g.bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run

sudo chmod +x bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run

sudo ./bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run

do the process next.

Answer (score 0):

After you download it, for example to Downloads Directory!
go to Downloads directory and open terminal

change the name of 
to something simple like  by right click on it and rename it

run these commands:

`chmod 755 bitnami.run`

`./bitnami.run`